# Symfony2: where to store code colors?

Tags: symfony

I want to store the code of several colors somewhere. Those colors
will be assigned to the nicks name in a chat when they login.

How to store those colors in the database? I mean, I know I can create
an entity Color and then create the fixtures file that would include
the color codes, but is that correct??

Is there any name for this kind of data that should be stored from the
beginning in the database? I didn't know how to search for it in
internet or give the title for this question.

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that bad, specially if you are using a one-to-one mapping, i.e. a user have one nickname color. This implies that colors are not shared across users.

But if I had to do it, I would store this value as a string in my entity. Something like nicknameColor with appropriate setter and getter. The string would be the HTML color code, something like `#a8a8a8`. You could store the dash or not, it's up to you.

I would do this because it is an object Color would have only a single field which I find kind of useless. It would maybe save a bit of workload but as I said, it is not that bad. It's up to you.

I'm not aware of a database manager having a special color type for a column type. I could be wrong but I'm pretty no database has that color type.

Then for the form, you could create a special form type that would show a color picker and serialize/deserialize the color to a string.

Comment: My personal preference is to store the color including the `#` as this will allow you to store CSS color names too and differentiate between them. Note that the maximum CSS color length is 20 characters with the value of `lightgoldenrodyellow` so you might wanna have a storage limit of 20 characters.